# How to emulate an Edge Triggered Flip-Flop?

Tags: c

I have a GPIO pin(GP4) on a microcontroller with a continuous digital pulse train coming into it. I am writing to it in C and do not have interrupts on this chip. I have been calling my input "#define inputA GP4". In C, I would like to be able to find the positive edge of a pulse and trigger the timer on it. I'm not sure if an XOR will accomplish what I need by storing inputA to another variable at some point. The other problem that I have is I need to be able to do this and not get caught in an infinite loop where I can still do other things sequentially with my code, if for instance, inputA goes to 0 and stays at 0 permanently. This means that my option of using while(inputA=0); is out of the question. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you know the maximum frequency of the input, what's an acceptable delay between the trigger and its detection, the frequency at which your core is running, or what percentage of your cycles you want to dedicate to other tasks?

Comment: My program counter on my chip is executing instructions every 128us. The incoming signal has a frequency range of anywhere between 25Hz and 533Hz. I would like to keep the delay minimal(under 800us). The cycles I can live with sampling only every second or so. This is not an infinite process by any means and a few hundred milliseconds of time between cycles not being checked is not a concern of mine.

Comment: Did you mean `128 ns` instead of `128 us`? If you're actually running that slow (low power mode maybe?), I don't see any alternative to busy looping to get a response in so few cycles. That doesn't mean you have to block if the signal gets pegged low, however. Another question: when you say you don't have interrupts, do you mean external interrupt pins or **any** interrupts at all (like say a timer peripheral interrupt)?

Comment: I do not have any timer peripheral interrupts. I do not have external interrupt pins either. My stack is limited to 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should write the old value to some variable.

A positive edge is define by the old value being `0` and the new one `1`. You should check exactly that:

```
char oldval, newval;
oldval = inputA;
while (1) {
    newval = inputA;
//    if (oldval == 0 && newval == 1) {
    if (!oldval && newval) {
        // positive edge
    }
    oldval = newval;
    // do other stuff
 }
```

Comment: I'm not sure that this code will wait for the positive edge trigger. The case where my pulse train isn't at a positive edge trigger location and my if statement is looked at by the code- They will not always happen simultaneously. In other words, the if statement will be overlooked if (!oldval && newval) is not true.

Comment: Assuming the numbers in [@Stumpyhuck29's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21563430/how-to-emulate-an-edge-triggered-flip-flop#comment32569060_21563430) are accurate, I don't think it's likely this will be able to meet them even if there is no `// do other stuff`

Comment: I apologize, my Program counter is not performing calculations every 128us. On my PIC12F510, I am using an 8Mhz clock with a program counter that instructs at 2MHz. This means that I will OVERFLOW every 128us with a prescale ratio of 1:1. I have options for prescale ratios of 1 to 256, and clock rates of 4 or 8 MHz.

Comment: @Stumpyhuck29 I see, that's a lot more reasonable then. I would do something similar to this answer, but you do have to make sure the rest of your code does not block for too long (a common example is sending serial data).